# Extension of Homeomorphism of boundaries

Tags: general-topology, diffeomorphism

Let $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be two open bounded sets with smooth boundary (boundary is a smooth closed curve).

Let us assume that we know
$$\Phi \colon \partial A \to \partial B$$
is a homeomorphism. Is there a way to extend $\Phi$ to be a diffeomorphism $\tilde{\Phi} \colon A \to B$?

Comment: If $A$ is the disjoint union of two annuli and $B$ is a disk with three subdisks removed, then they are not even homeomorphic, but there is a diffeomorphism of their boundaries. Did you mean to add some connectivity assumption?

Comment: @DanRust Well, if the boundary is **a** (=one) smooth closed curve, I'd guess that $A$ and $B$ are both homeomorphic to the open disk.

Comment: Does this help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem ?

Comment: Ah, I missed 'closed', which implies connected. Thanks @HagenvonEitzen

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to prove this.

1. Both $A, B$ are simply-connected, bounded by Jordan curves. Consider the (conformal) Riemann mappings $r_A: D^2\to A, r_B: D^2\to B$, where $D^2$ is the open unit disk in ${\mathbb C}$. By [Caratheodory's extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(conformal_mapping)), both $r_A, r_B$ extend to homeomorphisms $R_A: \bar{D}^2\to \bar{A}, R_B: \bar{D}^2\to \bar{B}$ of the closures.
2. By composing, $f:= R_B^{-1}\circ \Phi\circ R_A$, we obtain a homeomorphism $f: S^1\to S^1$ of the boundary circle of the unit disk $D^2$.
3. Extend $f$ to a diffeomorphism $F: D^2\to D^2$ using, say, the [Douady-Earle extension](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douady%E2%80%93Earle_extension).
4. The composition
   $$
   r_B\circ F \circ r_A^{-1}: A\to B 
   $$
   is the required diffeomorphism extending the homeomorphism $\Phi$ of the boundary circles.